# spiral parametric curve and green's theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

given the parametric curve:
$$
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{X}(r)= \begin{cases}\left(\pi^{3 / 2} r^3 \cos \left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right), \pi^{3 / 2} r^3 \sin \left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)\right) & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \leq r \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \\ \newline
\left(\cos \left(\pi+r-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right), \sin \left(\pi+r-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)\right. & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \leq r \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}+\pi\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
i have  proved that its a closed, simple, continuous curve with a finite length but not a $c^1$pw curve (at t = 0 the derivative cannot be defined continuously) and now i need to show that for any $f {\in} C^1$ $ \iint_{\Omega} \nabla \times \boldsymbol{f} d x_1 d x_2=\oint_\gamma \boldsymbol{f} \cdot d \boldsymbol{x}$ when ${\Omega}$ is the interior region of the curve (the green's theorem). A hint would be very helpful.